# SEO - duplicate content with Javascript slide deck

Tags: javascript, html, seo

I have a slider which works like this:

- When sliding to an item the URL changes using the [HTML5 History API](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/)
- If a user enters an item's URL (e.g. "*/slide-5*") directly the slider shows the respective slide.
- The navigation of the slider consists of `<a>`-elements with their respective `href`-attribute (e.g. `href="slide-5"`).

This works fine and even with JavaScript disabled the user can see every slide's content.

My question is: A search engine is going to crawl all links. But basically all this URLs are have the same content. Can this have negative effect on the page rank? And if so, what would be the best solution to this problem?

---

If this indeed effects the page rank, would this be a valid solution:

- Only the requested slide's content is on the page.
- The content of the next requested slide is loaded via XHR.

---

<sup>For current visitors: This post from 2012 is very old now. At this time the History API didn't have a good browser support and it wasn't really clear how search engine handle JavaScript. This has changed drastically in the last years and you can find sources to cover the topic at hand. Still, this is very opinion based.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might affect your SEO.. It might not. But to be sure; have a look at Canonicalization.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066#2